# SSIS Package variable is not found during package execution through stored procedure in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-projects

I am trying to executed the SSIS package file (dtsx) stored at file server. in SSISDB catalog I have folder `dynamiFoldertest` and package `dynamiPackagetest`.

I am loading an external package `dynaPackage.dtsx` with package variables in `dynamiPackage` using stored procedure `catalog.deploy_packages`, which is successful as I can see `dynaPackage.dtsx` under

```
dynamiFoldertest => dynamiPackagetest => dynaPackage.dtsx
```

Then I start the package execution using stored procedure `catalog.create_execution` which is successful as I get an `ExecutionId` as out parameter. for next step is to set the package variables value using `catalog.set_execution_parameter_value` stored procedure for each variable using `@object_type` parameter value as 30 (indicating package variables). But for every package variable I get following error

> The parameter {variable name} does not exist or you don't have sufficient permissions

I checked in `internal.execution_parameter_values` and in
`catalog.execution_parameter_values`, there is no record for any package variable.

What might be reason for this?

Permissions: I can deploy package using stored procedure so I think I have enough permissions.

NOTE: I want stored procedure solution only and not using integration and DTS packages in c# as they are no more supported in .NET 6.

Please help.

Comment: We'll need to see the generated SQL calls to diagnose this. Please edit the question with an example of a dynamic run

Comment: apologies for late response, found another way. Thanks. how to see "generated sql calls"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using catalog.set_execution_parameter_value stored procedure to set package variables, I used catalog.set_execution_property_override_value stored he procedure and I am able to set the variable values.
More information =>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-execution-property-override-value?view=sql-server-ver16